# I have created my model but im confused with creating views to save my data from submitted form in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Aganwadi(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email= models.EmailField()
    district=models.TextField()
    phone=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have a template for the the form called aganwadi.html in users/templates/users/aganwadi.html
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def Aganwadi(request):
    return render(request,'users/aganwadi.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),name='login'),
     path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'),name='logout'),
     path('aganwadi/',user_views.Aganwadi,name='aganwadi'),
     path('', include('pmmvyapp.urls')),

]
```

I want to store the data submitted on my form to be stored on the database

Answer (score 0):

inside the views.py function you could do what you want

```
def Aganwadi(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # considering html form has action=post
          username = request.POST.get('username') # provided that your form has field named username
          new_user = User.objects.create(username=username)
          new_user.save()
    return render(request,'users/aganwadi.html')
```

but the example is very far to be a product one
just for tip. it's more recommended to use django forms instead of html forms

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your model to save data u first have to create a form:

form.py

```
from django.forms import models
from .models import YourModel
class YourForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
```

Now u can use the ModelForm in your view. 
view.py

```
from .forms import YourForm
def Aganwadi(request):
    form = YourForm(request.POST or None) # initialize form or get POST data
    if request.method == 'POST': # considering html form has action=post
          if form.is_valid()
             form.save()
    return render(request,'users/aganwadi.html', context={'form':form})
```

At the end you have to use the form in the html file...
aganwadi.html

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Save     </button>
</form>
```

I highly reomand you to go through the django [tutorial](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/)